# Comma separated numbers in rails 3.0.5 project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails project I have a form to enter a dollar amount. This amount is stored as an integer in a mysql database.

```
<%=f.label :Amount%><br/>
<%=f.text_field :amount%>
```

if the user enters the number using a "." separator like 2034.34 it works well. My problem is when someone uses a "," as in 2,034. This number is stored just as a 2 in the databases.  How do I get the app to store number with both comma and decimal separators?

**Update**

Nkm put on the right track but I got a stack too deep error. I ended up using

```
def amount=(amt)

  write_attribute(:amount,amt.gsub(",", ""))
end
```

Comment: Have you reviewed http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the database column is `decimal/float`, we should process the data into the right format before saving.

You can either go with `activerecord` `before_save` callback or override the setter method of that attribute as follows,

```
#model.rb
def amount=(amt)
  self.amount = amt.gsub(",", "")
end
```

Comment: override setter like this goes to infinite loop and could crash on stack level too deep

Answer (score 1):

You ask to store the amount as a formatted String in the database. I think it's a really bad idea: it will be difficult to do calculation with this string (sums, comparison, etc...). Use a `float` column instead.

You can use a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) (*I hope they're available in 3.0.5*) on your ActiveRecord model to remove the comma before saving. For example

```
before_save :format_amount

def format_amount 
  self.amount.delete! ','
end
```

Use [NumberHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) to display back the comma in your view.

Answer (score 1):

You may add `before_save` [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) in your Model to convert commas to dot .

```
before_save { self.amount.gsub!(/\,/, "." }
```

irb example:

```
"2,034".gsub!(/\,/, ".")
# => "2.034"
```